# Why I can make my question favourite

Tags: support, bookmarks

Why I can make my own question a favourite?

[image: what is this?]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think one reason is that you might have asked a lot of question and you might be more interested to track changes in some rather than others and, then, it makes sense to be able to track them via the favorite feature. After all if you hang around for a long time you might have asked a lot of question. This guess is confirmed by [an answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36517/163868).

Comment: @GevorgHindoyan I do not understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: maybe someone gave you a really good answer, and you star it for quick reference. I know I did this once for one of my questions.